# Ruby: returning a hash of key value pairs up to a given length of key value pairs

Tags: ruby, hash

Given a hash of arbitrary length, how do i return only a number of key value pairs (as a new hash) up to a certain point given as an integer?

For example:

```
hash = {a: 6, b: 2, c: 1, d: 5, e: 3, f: 4}
desiredlength = 3
desiredoutput = hash = {a: 6, b: 2, c: 1}
```

(In my example I deliberately gave the hash values as random numbers, since I'd like a method that does not rely on the content of the values like .sort, just the order in which they appear in the hash)

This seems like it should be simple but I haven't found a good method yet.

I did come up with this method:

```
Hash[hash.to_a[0, desiredlength]]
```

This takes the original hash, turns it into an array, and converts the range of 0 to desiredlength back into a hash

... but it feels super clunky and rubocop doesn't like it

Comment: `hash.take(3).to_h` would work.

Comment: Thanks! This worked and is nice and simple

Comment: Note: Please keep in mind that the current `Hash` implementation in Ruby orders key/value pairs in the order in which they were inserted. But [Hash tables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table) in other languages or in general are considered to be unordered data structures. Therefore "take the first x key/values" might return indeterministic results in other languages (or very old versions of Ruby).

Answer (score 3):

As with many things in ruby, There's More Than One Way To Do It.

Here's one:

```
hash = {a: 6, b: 2, c: 1, d: 5, e: 3, f: 4}
hash.first(3).to_h
  #=> {:a=>6, :b=>2, :c=>1}

# Or, similarly:
Hash[hash.first(3)]
```

See: [`Enumberable#first`](https://apidock.com/ruby/Enumerable/first).

Answer (score 3):

```
hash = {a: 6, b: 2, c: 1, d: 5, e: 3, f: 4}
desiredlength = 3
```

```
hash.select { (desiredlength -= 1) >= 0 }
  #=> {a: 6, b: 2, c: 1 }
```

See [Hash#select](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Hash.html#method-i-select).

---

Another way:

```
hash.slice(*hash.keys.first(desiredlength))
  #=> {a: 6, b: 2, c: 1 }
```

See [Hash#slice](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Hash.html#method-i-slice).

Comment: `hash.select.with_index { |_, i| i < 3 }` would work too.

Comment: @Stefan, true, but that's less opaque.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way it can be done:

```rb
hash = {a: 6, b: 2, c: 1, d: 5, e: 3, f: 4}
desiredlength = 3

hash.take(desiredlength).to_h
```